# Parameterizing an implicit curve

Tags: exponential-function, parametric, implicit-function-theorem

I have to parameterize this curve:

$$F(x,y)=y-x^2+x-e^{-yx^2}=0$$

But I don´t know how to do it.
thanks

Comment: I do not know either but I would mention that you can make $y$ explicit using Lambert function $$y=\frac{W\left(e^{(1-x) x^3} x^2\right)}{x^2}+(x-1) x$$